# Add CSS dynamically to a control in UI5

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to add a CSS property dynamically to a control.
I have a group of `RadioButton`. On selection of any one of the buttons, I want to make one layout visible.
Below are some of the snippets I tried, none of them seem to work!

Snippet-1

```
showhide: function(){
    var fcid = sap.ui.getCore().byId("FC7");
    fcid.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Snippet-2

```
showhide: function(){
    var fcid = sap.ui.getCore().byId("FC7");
    jquery('#fcid').css("visibility","hidden");
}`
```

Snippet-3

```
showhide: function(){
    var fcid = sap.ui.getCore().byId("FC7");
    jquery('#fcid').hide();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `fcid.visibility = "hidden";` and expect it to behave like a DOM object; it's not, it's a Javascript class with getters, setters, events, aggregations, etc.

Therefore, you should use the control's properties instead: `fcid.setVisible(true);`

See the API docs for the correct signature of the control/layout properties

Answer (score 1):

You can:

```
var fcid = ...byId("FC7");
fcid.setVisible(false);
```

Or

```
fcid.$().hide();   // or every other  jquery method
```

Or

```
fcid.addStyleClass("hiddenObject");
```

Last one with Css-Class:

```
.hiddenObject { display:none; }
```